# Windows 7 login screen show only last user and "Other User" icons after profile problem

Tags: windows-7, login

I recently had a profile problem with my Windows 7 PC. My original profile in the registry had ".bak" appended to it and a new profile was created. I was unable to login with the new profile. I fixed this immediate problem by logging on in safe mode. This enabled me to restore my original profile.

However, since that moment the login screen now operates differently. Instead of showing icons for all the users with accounts on the PC, it now only shows two icons. The first icon is the last user who logged on and the second icon always shows "Other User". I have tried several different solutions recommended by other people with similar problems, but none of them have fixed the problem. I think the person who started this [thread](http://social.answers.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/w7security/thread/63cea659-f6a0-412d-a0b1-952a26c1df44?prof=required&wa=wsignin1.0) has the same problem, but none of the proposed solutions helped him either.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: A quick question: You can now access your account through "Other User" though right?

Comment: I'd be interested to hear what you figure out, because this is something that I would actually prefer.

Did you intend to have it set to have you type the username and password, or click an icon? Right now it sounds like it's stuck somewhere inbetween.

Comment: When I click "Other User" I can can login in as any valid user.

There are settings in the local security policy editor that control this functionality properly, but I appear to in no  man's land where none of the known registry settings seem to correct the problem.

Comment: What if you create another new (temporary) account? Does the icon for the new account get displayed in the welcome screen?

Comment: New accounts will not be displayed either.

Comment: Hmmm... this may not make a difference since your problem doesn't seem account specific but... in regedit, navigate to Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList. What's in there? Is there a S-1-5-21-xxxxxxetc subkey in there with a "ProfileImagePath" value that matches your user folder?

Comment: Can you give us a dump of everything in your `HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon` and `HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies` and `HKLM\Software\Policies` registry keys? Any abnormal settings in the registry are likely to be in one of these locations, and I'd be interested to look at what they contain.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm on a domain here, so I can't verify my ideas, but concerning the newest post in the thread you linked to, here is my thinking:

To display the user accounts and their profile images windows must scan the 
`HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList\` subkeys of the registry. If there are some some half-broken entries left after your repair of the user account, Windows cannot reliably read that profile. Instead of just skipping the profile and displaying the rest, which would practically disable the half-broken profile, it goes into the alternate logon mode. That mode doesn't need to display all the icons and names, and allows you to enter any profile's username. One could say it's somewhat more "robust" in this respect.

So my suggestion is to go to the ProfileList\ in the Registry and look for broken, double or superflous entries and export-then-delete them. Don't try renaming them, because ALL the subkeys of this entry are scanned, regardless of the names.

This is also in line with Ibrahim77's solution oveer there which basically is: except for your Administrator account, delete all profiles, delete all ProfileList\ Subkeys, delete all Profile Folders and start anew.

Comment: It worked! So Simple! Windows left a corrupted profile in the registry when it hiccupped. May this question & solution help others. Hopefully MS will fix it in a future version of Windows. Thanks Oliver.

Comment: That worked for me as well, except for one modification: I exported the whole ProfileList key. The exported reg file then contains all the original info for later restore in case of fsckup. Saves a few mouse clicks :)

Comment: +1, with more details (and a way to fix without loosing profile list): https://superuser.com/a/1404899/131936

Answer (score 1):

AN IDEA: go into control panel, then system properties, then change settings for "Computer name, domain, and workgroup settings". Next to "to rename this computer or change its domain or workgroup, click Change" click Change. Is there a "Member of " domain set there, by chance? Since your screen sounds like the one people have when they are a member of a domain.

Also check the rest of my comments. Did you try all the solutions in the similar thread you noted in your question? Some sound pretty decent. Also check the registry keys...

If you just can't bear it and nothing solves it, do a backup and reinstall. :)

ALSO: try looking through all the policies one last time though you might have already done so.

> Search for local security policy, run it...
>
> Then expand local policies then Security Options...
>
> For every policy that begins with "Interactive logon", make sure everything is right. e.g. for Display user info when session locked, it should be display name only or something like that. The rest are mostly disabled, not defined, or a couple enabled.

Other than that... scan for malware... I wouldn't know.

Comment: It seems unlikely that he would become accidentally attached to a domain, since becoming a member of a domain requires entering the domain admin password. That usually doesn't happen without the user realizing it.

Comment: true. Probably some detail in the registry then.

Comment: Interestingly, the workgroup reverted to "WORKGROUP" instead of the name I gave it. I renamed the workgroup back, but this has made no difference to the login problem!

Comment: You did try the "dontdisplaylastusername" trick right? (in the windows answers thread). I'm still trying to find a solution for you. :)

Comment: And check all the policies one last time :) (updated answer(

Comment: ALSO: check that `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\AutoAdminLogon`  is equal to 0 and not 1.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to do it through a graphical interface:

- Press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> to open the "Run" dialog
- Type `control userpasswords2` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
- Toggle the checkbox labelled "Users must enter a username and password to use this computer"
- If a password box appears I would recommend setting it to the same as the one you currently use for your account
- Restart

You should now see the users listed, not the "SomeUserName" and "Other User" configuration.

Answer (score -1):

Someone mentioned deleting the key

HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList\Default

Though if this is correct or works, I don't know.